# How to show marker in jqplot for the last point of the axis value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot, jquery-svg

I'm using jQplot to draw the line which gets input to X-axis as Date and Y-axis as Percentage Value. I want to show the marker only to appear on the end of the line. like attached image below.[image]

I wonder is there any option to show only the last marker in Jqplot. I know how to hide all the marker `{showMarker:false}`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show a single marker in the jqplot graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20920457/how-to-show-a-single-marker-in-the-jqplot-graph)