# How to show a single marker in the jqplot graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

Hi im using jqplot graph. I need to hide the Circular points that are currently displayed on the plot chart for each value in the array except the last point.

I use the following code to display the chart. I used "show marker : false" option,  but it hides all circular in the graph. Please help me how to show only one circular point in the graph.

```
<div id="chart2"></div>

var line2 = [['2012-10-02', 20],['2012-10-03', 45],['2012-10-04', 35],['2012-10-05', 32],['2012-10-06', 30],['2012-10-07', 25]];
var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart2', [line2], {

seriesDefaults: {
    showMarker: false
},

axes:{
    xaxis:{
      renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
      labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
      tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
      tickOptions: {
          angle: -90,
          formatString: '%m/%d/%Y'
      },
    }
  },
yaxis: {
     labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
},
highlighter: {
    show: true
  },

  cursor: {
    show: false
  }
});
```

I want to achieve the below screen as my output. please help me how this could be done. Any help will be appreciated.[image]

Comment: Try Highchart to generate chart www.highcharts.com

Comment: high chart is not free to use ... tats why i choose jqplot.. :-(

Comment: It free for noncommercial use, and you can also use open flesh chart http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way of doing this using `jqplot`. but you can achieve this by making the following changes: [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/nDKRA/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var line2 = [['2012-10-02', 20],['2012-10-03', 45],['2012-10-04', 35],['2012-10-05', 32],['2012-10-06', 30],['2012-10-07', 25]];
    var line3 = [['2012-10-07', 25]]; 
var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line2, line3], {

    series: [
        {
            showMarker: false
         },
        {
            showMarker: true
         }
],

axes:{
    xaxis:{
      renderer:$.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
      labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
      tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
      tickOptions: {
          angle: -90,
          formatString: '%m/%d/%Y'
      },
    }
  },
yaxis: {
     labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
},
highlighter: {
    show: true
  },

  cursor: {
    show: false
  }
});

});
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this answer. It's a lot of work, if you want to show just a few markers, but it works!